# UIWebView - adding an object to the address

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView that I'd like to load a web page and also append an object to the end of the address.

this is what I have:

**NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.wikipedia.org/%@",recipeName;**

the name of a particular recipe would be appended to the end of the URL

I'm getting the "statically allocated instance of Objective-C class NSString" error. Is my syntax incorrect or is it something else?

I've been looking at this for quite a while now and thought I'd ask the community here.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *urlAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.wikipedia.org/%@",recipeName];
```

Try this code it will work..

hAPPY cODING...

Comment: if I use:
NSString *urlAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/%@",recipe.name];

the UIWebView loads a blank page.

if I use:

NSString *urlAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/cheesburger"];

it loads fine.

I did a NSLog of recipe.name and it outputs to the console correctly.

any idea where I'm going wrong? thanks for your post.

Comment: maybe I should have said that recipe.name is coming from a core data/sqlite table. recipe being the entity and name the property

Comment: Check out whether your recipe.name is giving you any content or not. Just add the line before the above code

`NSLog(@"Recipe name :%@",recipe.name");`

and after the above code
`NSLog(@"URL :%@",urlAddress");`

And check out whats the output for both and if still you are not able to get the proper output post on the values you obtained here.

I think you are not getting any value in recipe.name.

hAPPY cODING...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`NSString *urlAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://www.wikipedia.org/%@",recipeName];`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create string with format directly, try [NSString stringWithFormat].

Well not fast enough I guess ...